# Resolving symbol AppModule in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, angularfire2

```
WARNING in ./~/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.js 3:40-54 "export
'InjectionToken' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angularfire2/angularfire2.js 4:26-40 "export
'InjectionToken' was not found in '@angular/core'
```

ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module

> /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin2/node_modules/angularfire2/index.d.ts, found
>   version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin2/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol
>   AppModule in /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin2/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving
>   symbol AppModule in /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin2/src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module
```

It seems you used the old version of angularfire2 package; Try

```
1.npm cache clean
2.npm install angularfire2 firebase --save
```